# Trying to get property of non-object laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel-5

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> ErrorException in SitioController.php line 16: Trying to get property
>   of non-object

Tengo un problema con el código. Alguna ayuda por favor?

---

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estos son los errores que arroja al intertar con el codigo que me has dado

Comment: Hola Ignacio, esta publicación ha sido marcada como de baja calidad por la comunidad. Por favor, edítala y añade más información así como el código y los mensajes de error en modo texto en lugar de como imágenes. Lee [ask] y completa el [tour] para más información (y para ganar tu primera medalla).

Answer (score 0):

mas rapido tu codigo seria asi;

```
$data = Configuracion::all();
return view('sitio.index',compact('data'));
```

y solo en la vista vas a pasarle el `{{ $data->nombre }}`

en el error estas tratando te obtener una propiedad que no es un objeto. cuando haces las consultas por lo general ya se viene un array en el cual el indice de ese array viene del 0, 1, 2, 3.... etc .. prueba y avisas.

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por responder, me ha dejado de generar error en dicha parte del código, sin emargo, me ha dado errores multiples en la vista.

Comment: excelente. deberias de mostrar los errores a ver

Comment: a mi me causa mucha duda, el OP en ningún momento muestra código de consulta, solo código de frontend, como es que sabes que eso de `all()` lo ocupa y lo necesita?